# cakephp - redirecting unauthenticated user on "Missing method" error

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

CakePHP authentication/redirection to "users/login" works great if I'm not authenticated and I try to open the page ie. "/posts/view/2".

But if I try to get ie. "/users/somethingNotExisting" then CakePHP threw

```
Missing Method in UsersController

Error: The action somethingNotExisting is not defined in controller UsersController

Error: Create UsersController::somethingNotExisting() in file: app/Controller/UsersController.php.
```

It's bad:

- I do not want to see error message
- Creating missing_action.ctp is not okay, in this case everybody can see the default layout (with menu etc.)

How can I force CakePHP to *redirect any unauthenticated unknown action to the login page?*

Comment: You usually don't redirect on 404s. This would create unnecessary overhead for your server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error message you are getting is only in development mode, if you set your debug level to 0 in `app/Config/core.php` `Configure::write('debug', 0);` you will get a normal 404 not found response wich you can customize to your liking in `app/View/Errors/error400.ctp`

if people see your menu when not logged in that is your own fault for not 'hiding' that part for not logged in users

The error page views are located at `app/View/Errors/`. For all 4xx and 5xx errors the view files `error400.ctp` and `error500.ctp` are used respectively. You can customize them as per your needs. By default your `app/Layouts/default.ctp` is used for error pages too. If for eg. you want to use another layout `app/Layouts/my_error.ctp` for your error pages, then simply edit the error views and add the statement `$this->layout = 'my_error';` to the `error400.ctp` and `error500.ctp`. This way you can hide whatever default layout and/or navigation you want

Comment: almost good. My default layout is rendered and visible. I would like to see only an 404 page, nothing more.

Comment: see my edit to use another 'default.ctp' for your error pages, so that you can hide whatever you want from your error pages